# Wordpress: Return posts of Author Name = Current Page Title

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a profile page in wordpress for each of the authors creating posts. Each page title will be equal to the authors name.

On this page I want to be able to display 'the_content' which will be some images and a bio of the author followed by the 6 latest posts from them.

What I want to do is create a query that displays the posts where author_name = the_title.

At the moment I have this which is only displaying the author that I specify (eg. John Smith).

```
$author_posts = new WP_Query();
$author_posts->query( array( 'author_name' => 'John Smith', 'posts_per_page' => 6) );


while ($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post(); 

//DISPLAY POST CONTENT

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use get_the_title() function.

```
$author_posts = new WP_Query();
$author_posts->query( array( 'author_name' => get_the_title(), 'posts_per_page' => 6) );


while ($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post(); 

//DISPLAY POST CONTENT

endwhile;
```

See this link to learn more about get_the_title() function.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Comment: @jogesh_p Thanks for notifying it to the newcomer :)